# ¿Cómo cambio el valor de un objeto dentro del estado en React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, javascript-objeto

Tengo el siguiente estado inicial en el constructor de un componente.

```
  this.state = {
  Turnos: {
    TurnoCredito: 0,
    TurnoDesembolso: 0
  }
};
```

Quiero incrementar de manera independiente el valor de **TurnoCredito** y **TurnoDesembolso** que se encuentran dentro de **Turnos**, utilizando la función:

```
aumentarNumerador = opcion => {
if (opcion === "creditos") {
  this.setState({
    Turnos: {
      TurnoCredito: this.state.Turnos.TurnoCredito + 1
    }
  });
}
if (opcion === "desembolso") {
  this.setState({
    Turnos: {
      TurnoDesembolso: this.state.Turnos.TurnoDesembolso + 1
    }
  });
}
```

};

Pero al ejecutar algunas de las dos opciones, ejemplo "creditos", incrementa el valor de **TurnoCredito** pero afecta al key **TurnoDesembolso** y suprime su valor, arrojando el siguiente warning:

```
Warning: Received NaN for the `children` attribute. If this is expected, cast the value to a string.
in button (at Numerador.js:54)
in div (at Numerador.js:52)
in div (at Numerador.js:51)
in Numerador (at src/index.js:11)
in div (at src/index.js:10)
in App (at src/index.js:17)
```

¿Cómo podría hacer para cambiar de manera independiente los valores del objeto **Turnos** ?

Comment: ¿Has probado con un `spread operator`? Algo como: ```this.setState({
    Turnos: {...,
      TurnoDesembolso: this.state.Turnos.TurnoDesembolso + 1
    }
  }```

Comment: Porque lo que pasa es que efectivamente estás cambiando el valor del objeto y estás desechando el valor de la otra propiedad cuando se ejecuta alguno de los dos `setState()`.
Sí no te resulta, por favor, amplía el código. Es decir, agrega el componente completo pero simplificado, lo suficiente como para que solo tenga lo que te genera el problema y podamos abarcarlo y hacer pruebas.

Comment: Sin la coma antes del spread operator, lo siento. Solo: `...`.

Comment: Por lo menos de la siguiente manera no me está funcionando:     this.setState({
        Turnos: {...TurnoCredito: state.Turnos.TurnoCredito + 1}
      })

Comment: Dale, me equivoqué, ya estoy montando una solución con la explicación.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lo que pasa con tu implementación es que al hacer esto:

```
this.setState({
    Turnos: {
      TurnoCredito: this.state.Turnos.TurnoCredito + 1
    }
  });
```

Estás sobreescribiendo el objeto `Turnos` que tiene las 2 propiedades: `TurnoCredito` y `TurnoDesembolso` por un objeto que solo tiene una de las dos propiedades dependiendo de cuál condición se ejecuta.

Ahora observa mi solución:

```
aumentarNumerador = opcion => {
    if (opcion === 'creditos') {
      const nuevoTurnos = { ...this.state.Turnos };
      nuevoTurnos.TurnoCredito = this.state.Turnos.TurnoCredito + 1;
      this.setState({ Turnos: nuevoTurnos });
    }
    if (opcion === 'desembolso') {
      const nuevoTurnos = { ...this.state.Turnos };
      nuevoTurnos.TurnoDesembolso = this.state.Turnos.TurnoDesembolso + 1;
      this.setState({ Turnos: nuevoTurnos });
    }
  };
```

Si te fijas, utilizo variables, digamos, temporales constantes (`const`). ¿Por qué las utilizo? Porque con los arreglos y los objetos es óptimo utilizarlas, los arreglos y objetos efectivamente cambian sus valores internos pero no su referencia.

Para asignarle algo a esta variable `const` hago uso del *spread operator*: `...`, esto con el fin de copiar el valor del objeto y no su referencia porque si fuera su referencia podría intentar cambiar el valor de `this.state.foo` sin el `setState()` lo cual sería caótico. Así:

```
const nuevoTurnos = { ...this.state.Turnos };
```

Luego, cambiamos el valor de la propiedad que necesites, en este caso:

```
nuevoTurnos.TurnoDesembolso = this.state.Turnos.TurnoDesembolso + 1;
```

Y finalmente hacemos uso del `setState()` para actualizar el objeto `Turnos` (y no sus propiedades particulares porque sobreescribe la estructura del objeto).

```
this.setState({ Turnos: nuevoTurnos });
```

Otra forma menos elegante y más verbosa es hacer como lo estás haciendo pero también volver a escribir el valor de la otra propiedad del objeto sin modificaciones, así:

```
this.setState({
    Turnos: {
      TurnoCredito: this.state.Turnos.TurnoCredito + 1,
      TurnoDesembolso: this.state.Turnos.TurnoDesembolso
    }
  });
```

Esto con el fin de que se mantenga la estructura del objeto, pero imagina que ese objeto o state tiene muchas propiedades. Tu código se hará cada vez más verboso con esa implementación.

Por último, quisiera mostrarte algo altamente recomendable (probablemente sería lo mejor de implementar independientemente de su verbosidad).

Cuando utilizamos `setState()` para actualizar un state debemos tener en cuenta de que el valor del state y el momento en que estableces un nuevo valor podrían estar desfasados en el tiempo por que estos son asíncronos (muy importante, sobretodo si manejas soluciones de precisión, como un cronómetro que cuenta en milisegundos o nanosegundos).

Esta sería la implementación correcta para evitar problemas de sincronización:

```
//prevState de Previous State, estado anterior.
this.setState((prevState) => {
    return (
        Turnos: {
            TurnoCredito: prevState.Turnos.TurnoCredito + 1,
            TurnoDesembolso: prevState.Turnos.TurnoDesembolso
        }
    );
});
```

Observa que ahora tenemos una función anónima, función flecha o *arrow function* de Javascript que nos dice el valor del estado anterior, `prevState`, sin problemas de sincronización. Generalmente esto no te da problemas cuando actualizas muy pocas veces ese estado en un lapso de tiempo grande, pero aún así puede llegar a desfasarse.

> **Recomendación:** siempre que el nuevo valor de tu *state* dependa de un valor anterior de ese *state*, utiliza esa función.

Comment: Excelente solución https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/5219/parzival !!. Apliqué de esta forma y funcionó perfectamente, utilizando el const nuevosTurnos. Muy agradecido por tu ayuda !!.

Comment: Gracias a ti por formular una pregunta correctamente, de esa manera es más fácil ayudar.

Comment: También por la correcta explicación y argumento del uso de spread operator y lo demás.

Comment: Por nada, recuerda marcar el *check* de solución a la respuesta si esta solucionó tu problema. Bienvenido a StackOverflow.

Comment: Nuevamente te agradezco por la sugerencia y explicación del uso del prevState, nunca lo usé. Pero voy a probarlo e investigar más sobre sus posibles usos. Gracias !!.